# Retrofit get array with different objects

Tags: android, retrofit

I want to make `GET` request and get objects with different parameter names:

```
{
  "monday": {
    "open_time": "06:30",
    "close_time": "20:30"
  },
  "tuesday": {
    "open_time": "06:30",
    "close_time": "20:30"
  },
  "wednesday": {
    "open_time": "06:30",
    "close_time": "20:30"
  },
  "thursday": {
    "open_time": "06:30",
    "close_time": "20:30"
  },
  "friday": {
    "open_time": "06:30",
    "close_time": "20:30"
  },
  "saturday": {
    "open_time": "08:00",
    "close_time": "19:00"
  },
  "sunday": {
    "open_time": "08:00",
    "close_time": "19:00"
  }
}
```

So I made DayEntity but don't know how to use my monday, tuesday ect?
Service jsonschema2pojo wants to create lots of classes from Monday to Sunday.

```
public class DayEntity {

    @SerializedName("open_time")
    @Expose
    private String openTime;

    @SerializedName("close_time")
    @Expose
    private String closeTime;

    public void setOpenTime(String openTime) {
        this.openTime = openTime;
    }

    public void setCloseTime(String closeTime) {
        this.closeTime = closeTime;
    }
```

**UDP:** And if GSON could parse it well how to use it with Retrofit combination? I have WeekEntity and it returns me NullPointer in success()

```
public class WeekEntity {

    public HashMap<String, DayEntity> week;

    public HashMap<String, DayEntity> getWeek() {
        return week;
    }
}



  public void getBusinessHours(final Context context) {
            RestAdapter restAdapter = formatHeader(NetworkConstants.BUSINESS_HOURS_URL);
            restAdapter.create(ApiService.class).getBusinessHours(new Callback<WeekEntity>() {
                @Override
                public void success(WeekEntity weekEntity, Response response) {                
                    Log.v("~~~~~success", weekEntity.getWeek().toString());
                }

                @Override
                public void failure(RetrofitError error){                   
                }
            });      
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Best is to use Gson Plugin for android studio to convert `JSON` string to an InnerClassEntity.

1) download plugin from [here](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7654?pr=androidstudio) and install it in for android studio in **File/setting/plugin**

2) After installing, Create class and then **Right click/Generate/GsonFormat** and paste your response and click ok. automatically objects for your response(Json String) will be generated. Save and done.

3) you can iterate the array in onResponse then like this

```
public void onResponse(Response<ModelClass> response, Retrofit retrofit) {

       for (int i=0;i<response.body().getResponse().getArray_name().size();i++)
        {
         Log.i("TAG", "retro array :" + response.body().getResponse().getArray_name().get(i).getItem());
        }

}
```

and when you intializing retrofit assign `ConverterFactory` like this.

```
retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(API_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();
```

and in **build.gradle**

```
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:converter-gson:2.0.0-beta2'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class WeekEntity{
    HashMap<String, DataEntity> week;
    (...)
}
```

Parse your json into this und you get a map `dayname -> DayEntity`.

Comment: Now I have retrofit iteraction like this and it returns null as weekEntity all the time `@Override
  public void success(WeekEntity weekEntity, Response response) {
  }`

Comment: You are sure, that your server returns the JSON listed above?

Answer (score 0):

Gson 2.x is able to transform a JSON with variable keys in a `Map<String, DataEntity>`

Comment: Could  you please show how to parse it with retrofit? It is actually doing it automatically when the correct annotated fields are there and I am bit confused how to do it now.

Comment: what you posted is mostly correct. Don't use `HashMap`, use `Map` instead

Comment: which version are you/ is retrofit using?

Comment: can you add `compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3.1'`  and force it as converter `setConverter(new GsonConverter(new Gson()))` ?

Answer (score 0):

Your code should be like this.

```
public class DayEntity {
   public CheckTime monday;
   public CheckTime tuesday;
   public CheckTime wednesday;
   public CheckTime thursday;
   public CheckTime friday;
   public CheckTime saturday;
   public CheckTime sunday;
   public class CheckTime
   {
        private String open_time;
        private String close_time;
        //add your setter and getter here
   }
}
```